# Ember.js add css class for specific model id

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I am working on chat app. I have template of component - rooms

```
<div class='border rooms'>
    <button class="add-room-container">
        <div >Add room</div>
    </button>
    {{#each model as |room|}}
     <button class="room-container" 
             {{action "onRoomClicked" room.id}} 
             {{bind-attr class="currentRoomId===room.id:currentRoom"}}>
         <div class="deleteRoom" {{action "deleteRoom" room.id bubbles=false}}>
             X
         </div>
         <div>{{room.name}}</div>
         <div>{{room.createdAt}}</div>
     </button>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

and component js file
    import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    onRoomClicked(roomId) {
      this.set('currentRoomId', roomId);
    },
    deleteRoom(room) {
      console.log('room removed');
    }
```

}
});

and I have problem with the line

```
{{bind-attr class="currentRoomId===room.id:currentRoom"}}
```

I would like to check if current button is the last which was clicked (it is set in onRoomClicked) and if it is then add currentRoom class to button

I was trying to set dynamic property but I don't know how can I access current model (room) id from component and then compare it like I do in template

Answer (score 3):

You have many different ways to do this. But first the question is a bit what ember version you are using. In current ember versions `bind-attr` should not be used anymore!

So first I assume you call your component like this:

```
{{my-component model=rooms}}
```

I would strongly recommend to not call your data `model`! Give them a speaking name. Do something like `rooms=rooms`!

So now you are in your component. What you probably figured out is that the problem is your `{{#each}}` loop, which results in a situation that you have no `.js` file for the context inside the `{{#each}}` loop.

---

The maybe best way to work around is to use a second component, which you call inside your each loop:

```
{{#each model as |room|}}
  {{room-line room=room currentRoomId=currentRoomId}}
{{/each}}
```

Then you can place your `{{#each}}` body inside your `room-line.hbs`:

```
<button class={{if isCurrentRoom "currentRoom"}}>
....
```

And you have a backing `room-line.js` where you can calculate the `isCurrentRoom`:

```
isCurrentRoom: Ember.computed('currentRoomId', 'room.id', {
  get() {
    return get(this, 'currentRoomId')===get(this, 'room.id');
  }
})
```

---

Another way to handle this is to inject a `isCurrentRoom` into your `room`. This can be done with `.map()`, or with an `ArrayProxy` and/or `ObjectProxy`.

Something like this in your components `.js` file:

```
calculatedRooms: Ember.computed('rooms.@each.id', 'currentRoomId', {
  get() {
    return get(this, 'rooms').map(room => ({
      room,
      isCurrentRoom:get(room, 'id') === get(this, 'currentRoomId')
    }));
  }
}),
```

Then you can just use it in your `{{#each}}` helper:

```
{{#each calculatedRooms as |line|}}
   <button class="room-container {{if line.isCurrentRoom 'currentRoom'}}" 
     {{action "onRoomClicked" line.room.id}}>
    ...
{{/each}}
```

---

The third approach is to use a custom helper for this. This is maybe the easiest way to do it, but maybe also the ugliest, because you put logic in your templates.

A simple `is-equal` helper can help you:

```
export function isEqual(a, b) {
  return a === b;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(=);
```

Then you can just use it in your template:

```
{{#each calculatedRooms as |room|}}
   <button class="room-container {{if (is-equal currentRoomId room.id) 'currentRoom'}}" 
     {{action "onRoomClicked" room.id}}>
    ...
{{/each}}
```

If you choose this approch you can use [ember-truth-helper](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) which provides that helper, but you can also just write it yourself.

---

I would strongly recommend the first approach, its the far most elegant way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers), which gives you the incredibly useful `eq` helper in templates. Then you can write:

```
{{#each model as |room|}}
  <button
    class="room-container {{if (eq room.id currentRoomId) "currentRoom"}}" 
    {{action "onRoomClicked" room.id}}>
  </button>
{{/each}}
```

This is using an embedded `if` helper in your class attribute instead of `bind-attr` ([which is deprecated and you should avoid](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_bind-attr)).

Comment: I had the same answer. This one is a bit more explanatory though.